# Trying to deploy Spring app to Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, model-view-controller, tomcat7

I`m truing to make a simple Spring web application. I make the war file with mvn package. When e deploy the file to the Tomcat it gives me an exception that i can not fix. I will copy all my code here. I hope that someone will help me to fix my project.

HelloController.java

```
    package com.nikola.hellocontroller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;


public class HelloController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1)
            throws Exception {
        ModelAndView modelandview = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        modelandview.addObject("welcomeMessage", "Good Day.");

        return modelandview;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nenov</groupId>
    <artifactId>nenov</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>nenov</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>NENOV</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>tomcatserver</server>
                    <path>/nenov</path>
                    <username>tomcat</username>
                    <password>s3cret</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

HelloPage.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Spring MVC Application</h1>

    <h2>$(welcomeMessage)</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringTesting</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="HandlerMappping"
        class="org.springframework.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

    <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.nikola.hellocontroller.HelloController" />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The Exception that i can`t fix:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping] for bean with name 'HandlerMappping' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1325)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:623)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1394)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:957)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:705)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:246)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1346)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1317)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:623)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1394)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:957)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:705)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml the Bean configuration is wrong. The package for that class is wrong. Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="HandlerMappping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

    <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.nikola.hellocontroller.HelloController" />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

That should solve the `ClassNotFoundException`

In addition I would add a provided dependency to pom.xml to have the HttpServletRequest around:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: there was another wrong package. Completed the version :)

Comment: I made all that changes. Now there are no exceptions but when i deploy war file and to open it on this url - http://localhost:8080/NENOV/ it appears this error message:


HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.56

Comment: what is the name of the war file that is created? it seems the /NENOV context name is wrong. Make sure its upper / lowercase according to the war file

Comment: I also think you need to add the spring listener in web.xml to initialize spring at all:     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

Comment: I`ve fix my problem. The correct url was localhost:8080/NENOV/welcome.html

Answer (score 0):

try removing 4.1.1 for spring-websocket as well.
i think there might be a version conflict.

or run
mvn clean package
and take a look at the WEB-INF/lib in the target directory
you should see spring-webmvc-4.1.1.jar